# duvida sobre target="_blank"

Tags: javascript, html

Quando uso o target="_blank"
ele abre uma nova aba e foca nela
eu so quero que ele abre uma nova aba mas que o foco continue a pagina atual.

Comment: publicidade detected... ? xp

Answer (score 2):

Tem mas você precisa fazer isso usando `javascript`, só o link não vai conseguir.
Mude sua link para incluir uma chamada para uma função assim:

```
<a href="endereço-da-janela" target="_blank" onclick="return abrirJanela(this))">
```

Então na *function* você abre a janela e volta o foco pra janela atual:

```
function abrirJanela(link) {
    var novaJanela = window.open("about:blank", link.target, "width=500,height=500");
    novaJanela.blur();
    window.focus();
    novaJanela.location.href = link.href;
    return false;
}
```